# How to add a header area?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

Please tell me how to add a `header` area on this page. Photo below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare any new regions in your THEMENAME.info.yml file.
2. Print your region in page.html.twig.

If you declared

```
header: 'Header'
```

then you will print it in page.html.twig like this:

```
{{ header }}
```

After that you can create your custom block and place it in the newly created region.
For more details and info go to [Drupal 8 Docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-regions-to-a-theme).